Winterbash 2021
Our community is once again participating in Winter Bash with the rest of the Stack Exchange network this year. If you're new to Winter Bash, here's an explanation from the official FAQ:

What is going on? Why do I see hats?
From December 15th through January 5th, you'll be able to earn hats
all over the sites! Ask, answer, vote, edit, and chat, and you'll
uncover hats hidden in all kinds of places.

In the past, we have offered prizes for various activities during Winter Bash, but we have decided to try skipping prizes this year. Everyone will be earning hats for their own sake, so we'll hopefully avoid some of the shenanigans we've seen in the past. 
We hope that you all enjoy this activity as we work to keep our community welcoming and inviting as many new folks discover us over the holidays. Happy hat collecting!
